# How do I implement the axios API query params like this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

This is the first time I found an API like this, the form in the params key is like an array but maybe it's not an array and how is it implemented in axios?

{baseUrl}/list?filter[v3_p.name]=Package Data&filter[pro.name]=Indosat&filter[pp.category]=Voucher&filter[pd.is_enable]=1

My code in axios like this:

```
export const filterProduk = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const params = { filter: data }
    const res = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/list`, data, {
      params,
      paramsSerializer: function paramsSerializer(params) {
        return Object.entries(Object.assign({}, params, { filter: 'HIDDEN' })).map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`).join('&')
      }
    });
    dispatch({
      type: FILTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data.data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: FILTER_FAILED,
      payload: error.response.data,
    });
  }
};
```

and I have tried as well

```
export const filterProduk = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/list`, data, {
      params: {
        filter: [data.package, data.provider, data.category, data.is_enable]
      }
    });
    dispatch({
      type: FILTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data.data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: FILTER_FAILED,
      payload: error.response.data,
    });
  }
};
```

I don't get it in any documentation, and hope to get an answer here!
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`qs.stringify`](https://github.com/ljharb/qs#stringifying) to serialize the params. And you should pass the `config` object as the second argument to [`axios.get`](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases).

```
axios.get(`${baseUrl}/list`, {
  params,
  paramsSerializer: (params) => qs.stringify(params, { encode: false }),
})
```

---

A suggestion: You could set up the API base URL using [`axios.defaults.baseURL`](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults) or create a [custom axios instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#custom-instance-defaults) and configure it to avoid having to type it in every call.

```
// axios.js

import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.example.com'
})

// queries.js

import axios from './axios'

axios.get('/list', {
  params,
  paramsSerializer: (params) => qs.stringify(params, { encode: false }),
})
```

Comment: I have used it but its API url only read {baseUrl}/list there is nothing params filter[]=value ...

Comment: @Fery1320 Sorry, not sure what you mean. What happens when you use `qs.stringify` to serialize the params?